# Json.loads() not working when using python flask while the same snippet works in CLI

Tags: python, json, flask

So I basically have a python file which I'm using as a module (sl.py) with the main flask `app.py` file. The module runs a function which gets a json from an api and then puts the required stuff into a list named `info` which is used further used to display in the html. I get the input from "/" and display it in "/shlok".

sl.py:

```py
def get_shloka(ch, v):
    url = f"https://bhagavadgitaapi.in/slok/{ch}/{v}"
    r = requests.get(url)
    r = r.text
    r = json.loads(r)
    print(type(r))

    info = [r["slok"], r["transliteration"], r["purohit"]["et"]]

    return info
```

app.py:

```py
@app.route("/", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ch = request.form['ch']
        shlok = request.form['shlok']
        return redirect(url_for('shlok', ch=ch, shlok=shlok))
    
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/shlok", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def shlok():
    ch = request.form.get('ch')
    shlok = request.form.get('shlok')

    shloka = get_shloka(ch, shlok)

    return render_template("shlok.html", shloka=shloka)
```

I want it to simply display the contents of info in the html file of "/shlok" but instead it throws the following error:

```
    File "/home/risen/dev/gita-reader/app.py", line 35, in shlok

    shloka = get_shloka(ch, shlok)

    File "/home/risen/dev/gita-reader/sl.py", line 8, in get_shloka

    r = json.loads(r)

    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads

    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode

    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode

    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

    json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I'm unable to make out what the problem is because the exact same get_shloka() func even with the same args works fine in CLI.
[No errors with html]

Comment: Always check the response code before parsing the JSON.

Comment: Klaus D you mean printing the response before parsing? yes ive tried it says page not found. Prolly an error with the api link but the problem is that if it works fine in CLI but not in the site so it mustn't be something with the api link.